# Easiest way to classify these values?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of layer heights that I want to sort various `z` values into. The list should remain in descending order and the function should return the index of the layer the z value belongs to.

For example, for the `layers = [10,9,8,7]` the value `9` should be returned as `1` since that's the index of its layer, the value `8.5` should also be returned as `1`, the value `8` should return `2`, `7.9` returns `2`, and so on.

The function I wrote raises an error when it looks for an index outside the length of the list for the last layer.

```
def less_than(layers,z):

    index = 0
    current = layers[index]

    while current>z:
        index += 1
        current = layers[index]

    return(index-1)
```

So, what's the best method for producing such a function with these properties?

Comment: Look at the `bisect` functions: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/bisect.html

Comment: The bisect functions assume the list is ordered in ascending order, however my list has to be in descending order due to how other functions use it.

Comment: You could always write your own binary search...

Comment: Why should 8.5 result in 1? You said return the index where it belongs, and that's not where it belongs, is it? If you insert it there, then you end up with `[10, 8.5, 9, 8, 7]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `bisect`:

```
import bisect


class ReverseAccessor:
    def __init__(self, ls):
        self.ls = ls

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.ls[-(item) - 1]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.ls)


def less_than(layers, z):
    index = len(layers) - (bisect.bisect(ReverseAccessor(layers), z)) - 1
    if layers[index + 1] == z:
        return index + 1
    return index
```

This is a bit more complicated than your solution, but will theoretically perform better when the list gets large. We define a custom object that holds a reference to the original list and translates item accesses into their reversed form. That way, we can retain the O(log n) complexity of `bisect`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is fine, you just need to check that you are not trying to access elements that don't exist (I also simplified it a little bit):

```
def less_than(layers, z):
    index = 0
    while index < len(layers) and layers[index] > z:
        index += 1
    return index - 1
```

Apart from the index error this should behave exactly like your function.

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on `np.where`:

```
import numpy as np 

layers = [10,9,8,7]

def less_than(layers, z):
    return np.max(np.where(np.array(layers)>=z))
```

Example:

```
less_than(layers, 8.5)
```

output:

`1`

Answer (score 0):

If your list of layers is not that big and you don't really care about the O(logN) of bisect, here's a very simple O(N) solution:

```python3
import math

layers.index(math.ceil(z))
```

`ceil` is rounding `z` up, and then we use built-in method of list to find the index of the item.

You can substitute `ceil(z)` for `int(z + 0.5)` if you don't want any imports.